# Creating an Altair bar chart of the frequency of each letter in a sentence entered by the user help python

Tags: python, altair

Unsure how I can get this to work. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

```
import altair
user_input = input('Enter something here')
user_input_count = user_input.count 
data = altair.Data(letters = user_input, number = user_input_count)
altair.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(x = 'letters:N', y = 'number:N').display()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple ways](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-frequency-of-each-character-in-string/) to extract the frequency of a letter in a string.

Here is an example using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections:

```py
import altair

from collections import Counter

user_input = input('Enter something here')
# get letter frequency as a dictionairy
user_input_count = Counter(user_input)
# format dictionairy as altair data (I do not know altair,
# there might be more elegant ways)
altair_values = [{"letter": letter, "count": count}
                 for letter, count in user_input_count.items()]
data = altair.Data(values = altair_values)
# plot data, using letter as ordinal data and count as quantitative data
altair.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(x = 'letter:O', y = 'count:Q').display()
```

[image]

Comment: what's the point of keeping decimal values on y axis ?

Comment: No point at all @DeepakTripathi, that's just the way altair chooses to automatically format it. I guess the plot can be highly configured afterwards, sorting numbers etc, but for that one should know altair, which I do not ;)

Comment: Ohh got it. Its altair default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
import altair
user_input = input('Enter something here')
user_input_count = user_input.count 
print(user_input)
user_input = list(user_input.replace(' ', ''))# removing blank space
letters, counts = np.unique(user_input, return_counts=True)
data =pd.DataFrame({'letters': letters, 'count':counts})
altair.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'letters:N', 
    y = alt.Y('count:Q',axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1))
)
```

Using the question title `Creating an Altair bar chart of the frequency of each letter in a sentence entered by the user help python` as input this is what we get

[image]